How to identify the list of apps available for NFC payments in my device, also is there any default app set or not?
programmatically identification of list of available nfc payment app,
which have the HCE service
Tried to query all the packages, couldn't find any detail there.
But i was able to set my app as default by using the following
 fun setAsDefault(context: Context) {
        try {
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.setAction(CardEmulation.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
            intent.putExtra(
                CardEmulation.EXTRA_SERVICE_COMPONENT,
                ComponentName(
                    context,
                    HCEService::class.java
                )
            )
            intent.putExtra(CardEmulation.EXTRA_CATEGORY, CardEmulation.CATEGORY_PAYMENT)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }


you can use the PackageManager to query for services that handle the HCE for payment
 fun getAvailableNFCPaymentApps(context: Context): List<ApplicationInfo> {
       val pm = context.packageManager
       val intent = Intent(CardEmulation.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT)
       intent.putExtra(CardEmulation.EXTRA_CATEGORY, 
       CardEmulation.CATEGORY_PAYMENT)

      val resolveInfos = pm.queryIntentServices(intent, 
      PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
      return resolveInfos.mapNotNull { it.serviceInfo?.applicationInfo }
   }

you can read more here Android NFC
